# How to I make floyd triangle shape using for loop?

Tags: ruby, loops, nested-loops

I need output of Floyd triangle like:

```
1
0 1
1 0 1
0 1 0 1
```

I tried. I didn't get it exactly. Can anyone explain the logic?

This is the code I tried:

```
k = 0
for i in 1..5 
  for j in 1..5 
    if (i%2)==0; 
      k = (j%2==0) ? 1:0; 
    else; 
      k = (j%2==0) ? 0:1; 
      puts k,''; 
    end
  end
  puts
end
```

Comment: I've never heard of "Floyd's triangle", but [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%27s_triangle) says the elements are (unlike what you have) consecutive values. Is your "Floyd triangle" an array `arr = [[1], [0,1], [1,0,1], [0,1,0,1]]`? Do you just want to print it out, nicely formatted, or do you want to perform some computations with it. If the latter, what is the desired output?

Comment: No I want to use  a for loop...

Comment: I want output for above format only. I too don't know this is Floyd triangle or not I just saw from  google  and i get one C program they specified in that name.

Comment: As an aside, `for` loops are rarely used. I don't know if I've ever used one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code for output you are expecting:

```
k = 0
for i in 1..4
  for j in 1..i  // inner loop code runs i times for each outer loop iteration
    if (i%2)==0; 
       k = (j%2==0) ? 1:0; 
    else; 
       k = (j%2==0) ? 0:1; 
    end
    print k,' '; 
   end
   puts
end
```

[Click Here](http://ideone.com/3jdT1n) to see output.

You can also get idea about for loops through [this link.](http://www.codecademy.com/glossary/ruby/loops#for-loops)

Comment: Thank you fidato. It's works correctly.  Can you explain please in each step by step  for my clear understanding. I am a beginner in programming.

Comment: I am struggling in for loop concept especially I don't know how nested loop working. 'i' is a outer loop and 'j' is  a inner loop. I don't know how it's iterating in above code.

Comment: fidato's code is very clean. He is saying the outer for loop will run 4 times (once per level of the triangle). Then the inner loop will run i times for each iteration of the outer loop (in order to generate the horizontal data of each level).

Comment: Now I get some idea about this problem @ejsd1989

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you are still unsure i highly recommend toying around with nested loops a bit. Usually they become quite simple after seeing them in action. It also helps to step through them with a debugger or by hand on paper (doing it by hand is a great way to develop your code reading skills and is important for algorithm analysis in the long run)

Comment: How can i print reverse order in above triangle ? Any sugession

Comment: @PalPrasanth : reverse order means put '1' where '0' is there and vice versa, Right ?

Comment: you not understand right?? it should be in 1st line 1 0 1 0, 2nd line 0 1 0, 3rd line 1 0 and 4th line 1 like that @ fidato

Comment: @PalPrasanth : You need to do few modification for reverse the loop and you are done, I had created the working snippet for you, you can see it http://ideone.com/rvU5Ea

Comment: @PalPrasanth : You can tick this answer as a correct answer if you understood the for loop correctly :)

Comment: hmm..i got it I've to practice more then only i will improve my logical thinking thank you Mr.Fidato

Answer (score 0):

Alright the following should work, but i hope it's readable. If you need more explanation or have specific questions let me know

```
i = 1
while i <= 4 do
    if i%2 > 0
        output = 1
    else
        output = 0
    end
    j = 1
    while j <= i do
         print( "#{output} " )
         if output == 1
             output = 0
         else 
            output = 1
         end
         j+=1
    end
    print( "\n" )
    i+=1
end
```

Comment: Didn't mean to complicate things with while loops, but though it may help to see a different form of nested loops :P.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that in order to get the "triangle" shape of your output, you need your inner loop to increment from 1 to i instead of 1 to 5.

```
k = 0
for i in 1..5 
  for j in 1..i
    if (i%2)==0
      k = j + 1
    else
      k = j
    end
    print "#{k%2} "
  end
  puts
end
```

Comment: Hopefully the comments under fidato's post have helped you to understand the nested loops. I will explain my code here.
The line 
  for i in 1..5
means everything inside of that block will be repeated 5 times. First, "i" will be equal to "1", second "i" will be equal to "2" and so on until "5". 
The line
  for j in 1..i 
means everything inside the for block will be repeated "i" times. When "i" is "1", the block will execute once, with "j" equal to "1". When "i" is "2", the block will execute twice, first with "j" equal to "1" and then with "j" equal to "2". And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one line approach:

```
5.times {|line| puts (line + 1).times.with_object(""){|num, str| (num + line).even? ? (str << " 1 ") : (str << " 0 ") } }
```

to make it more clear:

```
lines = 5
lines.times do |line|
  str = ""
  line = line + 1 # 5.times runs from 0 to 4 and we need 1 to 5
  line.times do |num|
    # the condition is a bit different because I changes the code a bit
    if (line + num).even?
      str << " 0 "
    else
      str << " 1 "
    end
  end
  puts str
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The prefered ruby way:

```
layers = 4  # Change to as many layers as you want
layers.times do |i|  # i starts from 0
  (i + 1).times do |j|  # j also starts from 0
    print (i + j + 1) & 1, ' '
  end
  puts
end
```

The `for` way:

```
layers = 4
for i in 0...layers
  for j in 0...(i + 1)
    print (i + j + 1) & 1, ' '
  end
  puts
end
```